# save android:listSelector=" " ; position in shared preference in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, sharedpreferences

I tried to save `listSelector` value in my `GridView`, but it's not working. I want to store `GridView` item position value with

```
     android:listSelector="#ffffff" ;
```

I want to save the position after a user clicks on an item. Please guide me.

Thanks in advance